# Displaying text path in Caja (Linux Mint file manager)

Tags: linux-mint, filenames

In Linux Mint 13, the default configuration (under MATE) shows icons for the path rather than a text box containing the path.  This is a huge issue for interfacing with the command line or programs, where I often need to copy/paste the path.  The latest version of Ubuntu also has these annoying icons, but includes a small button to click to convert it to text-form.

Is there any way to force the file manager to show me the text form so I can copy/paste the active path?  Bonus points: How do I make this the default?

[image: file browser]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just press `Ctrl-l` - (l for Location) .. I used to prefer the text view full time (whe I first started using Ubuntu 10.04), but I soon realized that the directory icons are actually quite useful, as they are clickable..

If you prefer the keyboard over the mouse, then `Ctrl-l` is very fast...  Or do you want the text showing full time, for a mouse action?

You **used to** be able to make it permanent in Gnome2/Nautilus via this command

```
gconftool-2 --type=bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_location_entry True
```

but this setting isn't in available for Caja in any form in Mate's Configuration Editor. There are also other settings which have gone walkabout (and perhaps a few new ones)...

Comment: Thanks.  That's better than the current state of things, although I'd prefer it show full-time.  I copy/paste paths way more than I navigate through directory trees....

Comment: If you still want it to be on show full time, I assume that means that you copy/paste via *mouse selection* and *right-clicking* on *Copy*.. If that's the case, then you may be better off by utilizing Caja's adaptation of `nautilus-scripts`  (in Mate, it is a built-in add-on (I think that's an oxymoron :) ... you can write a simple `Caja/Nautilus` script which gives you the directory path by right-clicking on any file (or even sub-directory) in that particular directory, without the need to select any text; just right-click and click.. You can even assign it a shortcut key (via Gnome-accels)

Comment: That's cool.  I may check into that and write one up.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Take a look at this as a reference to both aspects; [caja-nautilus-scripts and gnome-accelerators](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=200&t=100114) ... The accelerators are applied via/to the `Scripts` entry in the main menu.

Answer (score 1):

This was bugging me for the longest time. I found the solution, at least for my laptop running tricia 19.1. I have yet to test it on newer versions of mate.

1. Open dconf-editor
2. search of location bar
3. See image below
   a. Click off for use default value
   b. Click on for use custom value
   c. save
   [image: dconf-editor]

Voila!
[image]

This is what it looks like on a later version of Mint Mate. It is found under /org/mate/caja/window-state/
[image]